# Install boost devel on archlinux

Tags: c++, boost, archlinux

I have a remote server configured on archlinux and I need to install the dev version of the boost libs in order to compile my program, more specifically `<boost/asio.hpp>`.

I tried `sudo pacman -S boost-libs` and it installed something but not the devel files, I also tried `sudo pacman -S boost-libs-dev` and it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that Arch doesn't follow Debian's naming convention. "-dev" packages in arch (or AUR), are generally "development BRANCH"; bleeding edge versions, not development files.  Development files are (generally) included in the normal packages.

Comment: This sounds like a separate question.  In any case; what are you trying to build?  What command are you running?  A single line of output isn't really enough.

Comment: You're right. If what I installed should be enough to build, then this is a separate questoin and I will ask it in another thread.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$ pacman -Ss boost
extra/boost 1.49.0-2 [installed]
    Free peer-reviewed portable C++ source libraries - Development
extra/boost-libs 1.49.0-2 [installed]
    Free peer-reviewed portable C++ source libraries - Runtime
```

You need "boost".