# Linking boost::asio using terminal

Tags: c++, boost-asio, archlinux

I am trying to link `boost::asio` using terminal (I'm also using a text editor).

## What I tried

I did some researches on Internet (I didn't found nothing about my distro) - I found I must install that library by executing the following command on the terminal:

```
sudo pacman -S libboost-all-dev
```

This is the output I get:

> error: the following package was not found: libboost-all-dev

## Final question

How can I install and link correctly `boost::asio` with my `.cpp` file?

**Notes:**

- I'm using Archlinux

Comment: How can you link something with your text editor?! Maybe you mean "command line" or what?

Comment: @ForceBru correct. I edited my question

Comment: I know it's out of the direct question, but I suggest you to use CMake as project manager and handle Boost with it. 
Using CMake, you can even give compiler options to use Boost with Multithread support or link statically/dynamically your targets with it.

Check this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3917033/2369389

Comment: @orlow65 `-lboost_system` should be enough. Additionally, if you use threads to nicely scale `asio` then you also need `-lboost_thread`.

Comment: @GreenScape could you tell me the accurate name? If I add `-boost_system` as parameter i get errors...

Comment: @orlow65 those are parameters to `gcc` or `clang`.

Comment: @orlow65 to install package it seems that you need `pacman -Ss boost`

Comment: @GreenScape already installed. This is the command I tried: `g++ /home/hlw/Desktop/code.cpp -lboost-system` - but I still get dat error (not found):/

Comment: @orlow65 So you should try `-lboost_system`, as I wrote before. There's underscore (`_`) between `boost` and `system`.

Comment: @GreenScape you solved my problem! A genius! Thank you!

Comment: @orlow65 you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a package in Arch Linux, do:

```
sudo pacman -Ss boost
```

This will list packages with the string `boost`. Or, you can look up on the package website: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/boost/

One thing you should understand about boost is that a majority of its modules are header-only; if the linker complains about undefined references then you would have to link the required files. To link boost-asio, you would do

```
g++ -lboost-system <source> <exe>
```

Comment: I get: `/usr/bin/ld: unable to find -lboost-asio \n collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` - but I just installed them

Comment: I checked my own system for boost-asio; there's no need to link it. But it's a good idea to link `boost-system`. In which case, boost-asio is a header-only module.

Comment: if I don't link boost-system I get errors! But when i try to compile with -lboost-system paramenter i get something like: `unable to find boost-system`! :(

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I solved my problem!

Comment: can you please share how you discovered to use -lboost-system? It doesn't seem to be in the boost docs, the g++ man page does not contain it either. And my system does not seem to recognise -lboost-system at all!

Answer (score 1):

[How to install boost in Arch Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11198385/1036311)

You cannot link libraries inside your *.cpp files. You should enumerate required libraries using the -l option in the g++ command line.

```
g++ -lboos-asio -lboost-system myfile.cpp -o myapp
```

Comment: I get: `/usr/bin/ld: unable to find -lboost-asio \n collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` - but I just installed them

Comment: I have remembered that boost-asio is harder-only library. Link just boost-system.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I solved my problem!